# Hide optional content group in PDF with borb for python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, borb

I am following this tutorial to add an OCR-layer to scanned PDFs: https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#72-performing-ocr-on-a-pdf

However, unlike the pictures in the tutorial, the OCR-layer gets overlayed over the scanned image in the output PDF by default.
[image]

Is there a way to hide this layer before saving the output PDF?

Comment: Yes, but as far as my understanding of the tutorial is correct the ocr layer should be hidden by default. I tried multiple viewers, so I assume it has to do with borb.

Comment: Author of borb here. I may be wrong in saying the layer is hidden by default. Or it may be some viewer issue. I agree with the previous comment. Simply raise an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I checked the original tutorial (for StackAbuse). It does not promise that the layer will be hidden by default. It only mentions that you can toggle its visibility. And I show the layer being both visible and invisible.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Do you have any suggestion on how to modify the borb-repo so that it will be hidden by default? In the end, the PDF with OCR should work on all common viewers because I can not guarantee that all users using the PDFs later on will have access to a viewer that allows turning the layer off manually. Thanks!